# how to use libfaketime to setting system date

Tags: docker, sysdate

I use docker container to run tomcat.

Now I want to modify system date to use `date -s '2012-12-25'`, but can not have privilege. So I use
[libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/) to faketime,as below

`$LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="+1d"`

but only effectively current session.

So what can I do to effective the system date in container? Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you execute this command `$LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="+1d"` ? after `docker exec -it $image_name bash` ?

Comment: yes, in the docker container that running tomcat

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container

Comment: Thanks, But I want use bash to change faketime value in already-running processes in the container @chintanthakar

Comment: have you tried this answer  ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41548434/1895073

Comment: Thanks, my project is build as .war archives with Maven, and I could not modify the code now, So the answer counld not help me. @chintanthakar