# Change date inside container

Tags: date, docker, time, containers

I have problem with dynamically date change inside container. What I have:

```
docker run -it --privileged myDocker
```

the command above run container with privilege to change date

I can change date by:

```
date --set "12-12-12"
```

but after a few seconds, the date and time are setted the same as the host

```
root@660acd776c6b:/# date --set "12-12-12"
root@660acd776c6b:/# date
Wed Dec 12 00:00:01 UTC 2012
root@660acd776c6b:/# date
Wed Dec 12 00:00:02 UTC 2012
root@660acd776c6b:/# date
Wed Dec 12 00:00:02 UTC 2012
root@660acd776c6b:/# date
Tue Jan 15 10:14:26 UTC 2019
root@660acd776c6b:/# date
Tue Jan 15 10:14:27 UTC 2019
```

The container doesn't have installed ntp.
I can't use `faketime` because I use the date in .net application which doesn't use time from `faketime`. I can't change system clock using `faketime`.

How could I disable synchronization between container and host ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible change date in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container)

Comment: Short answer: you can’t, there is only one clock (assuming you’re not using one of the VM-based non-Linux solutions) and no “synchronization” _per se_.