# Mock time in docker(-compose)

Tags: docker, date, time, docker-compose, mocking

With the scope of testing a docker image executing a job, I would need to mock a container date during its execution, in order to do some accurate testing involving time.

Looking around the internet I didn't find any solution yet, just some paths that can be followed.
What I need is a way to change the system date, without having to connect manually to a shell, I'm planning to setup the tests using docker-compose, and I would like to configure the date as a configuration parameter.

Do you ever had similar experience? How did you solved?

First issue is changing the date, I've only found the `date` command to do it.

I'm looking for 2 methods:

1. Extend the base image and execute `date` before the `entrypoint`.
   I don't feel to re-create an image for each container a problem, but I don't like the fact that I can't "proxy" the entrypoint, the only way I've found to execute the `date` command is to redefine the entrypoint with an `sh` that execute it and then call the old entrypoint, but it have to "know" what it was, I didn't find a way to do whatever the base image is.
2. Use an *NTP* server. I'm a less-than-a-junior on this matter, but I was thinking about injecting in the network created by docker an ntp server that tells my mocked date to the other containers in its network. But I didn't find a way to configure a mocked ntp server in docker with fake time.

Currently I'm stucked, also a "*You can't use the NTP server because blablabla...*" would be helpful, or if you have some way to do it would be also better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually can't change the date inside my docker container. The docker clock is synced to the system clock.

There are other solutions though: [Is it possible change date in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container)

From what I understand about ntp, ntp clients try and update the system clock. So presumably you can't use NTP because a naive installation will try and change the system clock and then will be unable to do so inside docker. Maybe there is an ntp client that mocks, but I think you're back to the same problem and you're likely better off using the mocking lib in that link.

Testing clock skew is important (https://aphyr.com/posts/299-the-trouble-with-timestamps) and I'm also surprised there isn't more about this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I found [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) to be useful for this. It installs a wrapper for this purpose called `faketime(1)`. According to the man page:

> The  given command will be tricked into believing that the current system time is the one specified in the timestamp.  Filesystem  timestamps  will also  be  reported  relative to this timestamp.  The wall clock will continue to run from this date and time unless specified otherwise (see  advanced options).

In your container, simply install `libfaketime` and use the `faketime(1)` wrapper like so:

```bash
faketime "2019-09-18 19:46:00" my-script
```

The library appears to be available in many distributions' repos; e.g. EPEL for RHEL-based systems:

```bash
dnf install -y epel-release && dnf install -y libfaketime
```

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```bash
apt update -y && apt install -y libfaketime
```

For Alpine Linux 3.18, the package is not available in the stable repo, but it is in the edge-community repo:

```bash
echo 'https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community' >>/etc/apk/repositories
apk update && apk install libfaketime
```