# Move the time and date inside the docker container

Tags: bash, docker, debian

I have script that work on time and date.
I'd like to move the "system" data and time inside the docker container (Debian)

I tried with
`date -s "7 DEC 2022 18:00:00"`, without lucky
I can't set from docker-compose or dockerFile, I need to manage the time inside the docker-container during my script

Comment: What specifically do you want to achieve with `date`?

Comment: I need to check the checklocktimeVerify and nlocktime in Bitcoin transaction using regtest, so I want to move the clock up to 10 minutes, 2hours or days

Answer (score 0):

This script starts a docker container with a time 15 days earlier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempdir="$(mktemp -d)"
mkdir -p "$tempdir"

docker build -f - -t faketime "$tempdir" << EOF
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=trajano/ubuntu-faketime  /faketime.so /lib/faketime.so
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/faketime.so DONT_FAKE_MONOTONIC=1
EOF

rmdir "$tempdir"

docker run -it --rm -e FAKETIME=-15d faketime bash
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i'd like to move the date during the container is running. At the moment I find a solution by a RPC bitcoin core command, using `bitcoin-cli setmocktime` and it's ok for my purpose.