# Dynamically Adjust System Time of Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure Function (dotnet) deployed that relies heavily on the current date/time for many operations.

We are writing an integration test suite for it and would really love to keep a blackbox approach. That is, we'd rather not internally mock the date/time if possible.

Is there a way to adjust the system time of the app service to achieve this? Ideally, there would be a non-intrusive way to achieve this, but I'm open to lightly-instrusive options

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure portal, in your App Service subscription, go to the Application settings menu.
Under App settings, add this setting:

Key = **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE**

Value = The time zone you want

[List of timezone values to use with linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could deploy using a Docker container and set the time in that as described here: [Is it possible change date in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container)