# Change the date and timezone of a container and get a shell to a running container with updated time and date

Tags: docker, date, containers

Requirement: Change the date and timezone within the docker container terminal

Lets say I wish to change the system date of a running container

when tried to run `date -s 2023-12-01` to change the date but it does not work and encounter following error:

```bash
root@691e271b0e6f:/# date -s 2023-12-01  
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 UTC 2023
```

Expected behavior:

```bash
root@691e271b0e6f:/# date -s 2023-12-01  
Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 UTC 2023
```

Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77912379/10053482

Comment: Containers don't have their own clock, and you can't usually change the date.  See for example [Is it possible change date in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container)  The suggestion there of using a library like libfaketime could work and wouldn't be specific to Docker, assuming you had a path to get a shell inside the process.

Comment: Using libfaketime could work and it requires building new image; but my question is about modify container when startup without changing the image and it can be done by adding system capability `SYS_TIME`; like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77912379/10053482

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add the system capability `SYS_TIME`, while we create and run a new container from an image and also pass env var 'TZ'

```bash
docker run -it --rm \
   -e TZ=${YOUR_TIMEZONE} \
   --cap-add SYS_TIME \ 
   ubuntu:latest \
   bash -c "date -s 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'; bash"
```

where:

`cap-add SYS_TIME`: to allow us change the system date of the container

`TZ=${YOUR_TIMEZONE}`: override the default timezone to custom value

---

Then in container shell, we can see the update system date and timezone

example:

```bash
docker run -it --rm \
   -e TZ="America/Los_Angeles" \
   --cap-add SYS_TIME \
   ubuntu:latest \
   bash -c "date -s '2023-10-11 11:11:11'; bash"

root@a953bcfa1ab9:/# date
Fri Oct 11 11:11:11 PST 2024
```

PS: Here host: `a953bcfa1ab9` is ubuntu container not host system

Comment: This changes the system date, full stop.  If you run `date` on your host system you'll see that's changed too.

Comment: No; host system date does not get changed by running the suggested command.